# Loader throwing error 2035: URL Not Found even when file exists

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, ioerror

I am writing an android app that will import an xml file from local storage. I am using the Loader class to get the file. When I try to load any given file off of local storage (/sdcard) I get the error URL Not Found.

I know the file exists and that the file path I provide is in fact correct. I know this because I traced `testFile.exist` and it returns true, meaning the path is correct and the file exists.

I have also ensured that I have storage permissions on the device by ensuring that `File.permissionStatus = true`. I have used remote debugging to see if it was possible that the internal storage is unmounted when connected via usb, but I receive the same error. I used URLLoader too, I get the same error.

I have also checked multiple paths to the same place, such as:

- `/sdcard/filename`
- `/mnt/sdcard/filename`
- file:////sdcard/filename
- file:////mnt/sdcard/filename.

I can successfully create directories, but for some odd reason Loader will not recognize any file URL in my internal storage. I don't know if it helps at all, but I am using a Samsung Galaxy S8 +.

Here is a very simplified code snippet that I am using to retrieve my file from my phone's internal storage:

```
var testFile:File = new File("file:////sdcard/sheet.xml");
trace(testFile.nativePath);
trace(testFile.exists);
var fileLoader:Loader = new Loader();
fileLoader.load(new URLRequest(testFile.nativePath));
```

Here is the output of the code above:

```
/sdcard/sheet.xml
true
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.
```

To the people who say I need to add event listeners, I did and I got exactly what error it throws even without the event listeners looking for the IO error. I could not find anyone who has this specific problem. I'm guessing its either an android problem where the directory is a different path or protected, or its the way the File object handles my path.

Comment: The **Loader** class is used to load SWF (Flash Player files) or JPG, PNG, BMP, GIF (image files). In order to load data files, text or binary, you need the **URLLoader** class: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html

Comment: As a side note, you might want to try **File.url** property rather than **File.nativePath**. I remember (without particular details, alas) having some problems there and I think **File.url** works better.

Comment: @Organis I have aready tried using the **URLLoader**, but I have yet to try **File.url**. I will try that and update.

Comment: @Organis I tried again using both **URLLoader** and **File.url** But I have received the same error, Error 2044/ IO Error 2032.

Comment: Just in case, Did you do **File.requestPermission()**? Since **Android 6** and **AIR 24** you need not only announce the permission schema, but also explicitly ask user for permission.

Answer (score 2):

pass your path to

```
var testFile:File = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sheet.xml");
```

Comment: What package contains Environment ? I don't know what to import to get that.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out what was wrong thanks to @Organis, thanks very much!

While my app did have the Storage permission, I had to specifically ask permission for the specific file I am trying to load, which is a pain because I think I will have to request permission for each file I try to load. It would be helpful if the error was changed from '2032: URL Not Found' to something along the lines of 'Error #: Permission Not Granted' so that I or someone else would know specifically the reason of the error.

Here is the fixed code:

```
var testFile:File = new File("/sdcard/sheet.xml");
trace(testFile.url);
trace(testFile.exists);
testFile.addEventListener(PermissionEvent.PERMISSION_STATUS, function(e:PermissionEvent){
    if(e.status == PermissionStatus.GRANTED){
        trace("granted");
        var fileLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        fileLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);
        fileLoader.load(new URLRequest(testFile.url));
    }else{
        trace("no storage access");
    }
});
testFile.requestPermission();
```

Comment: No, I think user have to grant permission only once. Here's the thing. In Android 6 they changed the permissions routine. Instead of making user grant all the manifested permissions at the "install app" dialog, they made apps to request most crucial permissions, like storage access, camera access, etc., thus elevating  the consciousness of user's action. The **File.permissionStatus** property shows, if you need to request it, or it is already granted. Normally, once user has granted that permission, you don't have to re-request it.